# UIScrollView not scrolling in iOS7 with autolayout on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with a 6 textfields in it and a button inside of it. There is not enough content in the scrollView to make it scroll.

But when the keyboard shows, I would like the scrollview to scroll so the user doesn't have to dismiss the keyboard in order to select another textfield that is hidden by the keyboard.

I am using iOS7 and have autolayout enabled.

Any suggestions?

I am using storyboards and the only code I have is the following.

reg.h file

```
interface registerViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In order to make a scrollview scrollable, the content size must be larger than the scrollview's frame so the scrollview has something to scroll to.  Use setContentSize to adjust the content size:

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

In this case, you should adjust the size to view.frame.width, view.frame.height + keyboard_height, then adjust the content offset once the keyboard appears:

```
[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 - keyboard_height)];
```

If for some screwy, autolayout-related reason this still doesn't make the view scrollable, implement this setContentSize function in viewDidLayoutSubviews in order to override the autolayout:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
}
```

EDIT: To reset the scrollview after dismissing the keyboard, reset the scrollview content size to the scrollview's frame and the offset to zero:

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.frame.size.height)];
[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
```

P.S. To animate the content offset, use:

```
[scrollview setContentOffset:offsetSize animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ok this works. Though didn't use the last section of code. The only thing is now when I dismiss the keyboard the scroll view is still scrollable. How do I undo or reset back to the way it was after I dismiss the keyboard? As I don't need it scroll anymore after editing the textfields.

Comment: To me this doesn't make much sense as autolayout should automatically inform the size of the content for the scrollview.

Answer (score 16):

There is a contentInset property of UIScrollViews, you can set the contentInset to make additional space at the bottom to allow for scrolling without changing contentSize.

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 100, 0.0);
scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
```

above code adds 100 points inset at the bottom.

By the way, there is an official document about this matter. It explains everything you should do. You can find it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html). You can find what you are looking for under the section 'Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard'

Comment: Great, I only had issues with UIScrollView autolayout not-scrolling on iPhone 4inch. Your code (I needed just 1.0 for bottom) solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Create Scroll view
2. Add View to the scroll view (In my case i added view as mainView).
3. [Set ScrollView autoresizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0TqD.png).
4. [Set MainView autoresizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdnnt.png).
5. To set the Scroll content Size equal to the view created add below line

Add the below line

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews

{

[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

self.scrollView.contentSize = self.mainView.frame.size;

}
```