# ScrollView doesn't scroll when it has a subview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview that I added to my viewcontroller in the interface builder and I managed to make it work so it scrolls. But whenever I put a button or another view in the scrollview it doesn't want to scroll.

I have used the color blended layers option in the iOS simulator and nothing is overlapping the scrollview in the area where I try to scroll.

How can I make it scroll even when I have subviews?

Comment: How are you adding the subviews? How are you setting the content size?

Comment: @Wain I just used the interface builder to add the subview. The content size was set using `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1800)];`

Comment: Try setting the content size in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: @Wain It's still not working. There is probably something really simple causing this that I'm just overlooking. If you have any more ideas what's wrong please post them. I'm pretty new to programming so it might be something very simple.

Comment: Log what the content size is in `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: @Wain It says 1800.000000 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check whether `scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;`. If it is NO, then make it YES.

Comment: @Srikanth I tried with and without delaysContentTouches and it's still the same thing.

Comment: It would help if you can update your question with some code.

Comment: are you using auto layout? does adding subviews to your scrollview mess with the constraints set earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with my scrollViews not scrolling if I have AutoLayout enabled in IB, so you may want to look into that. There's probably a way around this by using the proper constraints.

Comment: Thanks! AutoLayout was the problem I found out how to fix it in this [post.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20318430/2627671)

`-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1800)];
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the `contentSize` of your scrollview, if the contentSize match the size of the screen, the scrollView won't scroll since it is not needed.

```
self.scrollView.setContentSize = mySubView.frame.size;
```

Comment: I did set the content size to 1800 by using `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1800)];` and it works when the scrollview is empty but not when I put something in it.

Comment: What kind of view are you putting in it ? You could have problem if you're embedding `UIView` which have a `UIScrollview` (like `UITableView` or `UIWebView`)

Comment: I have tried UIButton and UIView, neither of them work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the scrollView`s contentSize. Normally，the contentSize is the sum of all subviews`s height.
please read UIScollView referense.

```
    self.scrollView.contentSize = mySubView.bounds.size;
```

Comment: I did set the content size to 1800 by using `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1800)];` and it works when the scrollview is empty but not when I put something in it.

Comment: I used the code below and the rest is interface builder stuff.

`-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1800)];
}`

I also linked my scrollView in ViewController.h.

Comment: is it your button`size bigger then scrollview`s size ,not the content size .

Comment: try add a UIView in the scrollView.