# Adding Scroll view using storyboard in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to add a scroll view using storyboards in iOS. I have done so and it is working, but the problem is when I am using a scroll view of content size more than 800 it is not working. I have gone through many tutorials and have found that it will work only when autolayout is unchecked. Can we make it work with autolayout selected? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a scrollview scrollable, the content size must be larger than the scrollview's frame so the scrollview has something to scroll to. Use setContentSize to adjust the content size:

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

refer this link [UIScrollView not scrolling in iOS7 with autolayout on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317980/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-in-ios7-with-autolayout-on)

Answer (score 0):

try this
add the method

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SOME_FLOAT_VALUE, SOME_OTHER_FLOAT_VALUE)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I continue to have difficulties with this also.  This is what I have tried.  It works well, but I do get a warning, maybe someone can comment and help us all out.

Keeping auto layout on I have done the following..

In my view controller I dropped in a scrollview and sized it to whatever size was needed, but either the size of the screen or smaller. I then set the following constraints with the pin and alignment tabs for the scrollview...  Top to view, bottom to view, both sides to view, and center in container.  This allows for rotation.

Then, I dropped in a view and sized it to be larger than the scrollview.  I have extended both the length of the view and its width for different apps.  Inside this view you put all of your subviews, (image views, buttons, whatever you need) to be contained in the scrollview.  For this view I have also set the following constraints...  Top to scroll, bottom to scroll, width, and center in container.  Then in the left screen for the storyboard I selected the bottom constraint for the view.  It should be some negative number.  In the attributes inspector, I then made this bottom constraint 0.

This has worked for me in the past, I can scroll in both portrait and landscape.  I have also added pinch gestures and pan gestures for the view to be able to move things around.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
  {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
     [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SOME_FLOAT_VALUE, SOME_OTHER_FLOAT_VALUE)];
  }
```

for ipad(IOS7)

```
SOME_FLOAT_VALUE=0;
SOME_OTHER_FLOAT_VALUE=1200;
```

This is enough for scrolling a view