# Horizontal ScrollView Xcode 6 not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

i have created a scroll view which i want to work on a horizontal axis.  I created it as follows.

in my scrollerViewController.h file

```
@property IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

and in my scrollerViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

    [self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(968, 263)];

}
```

In storyboard my scrollerViewController simulation size i have made the width 1000 and the scroll view width and height to match  [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(968, 263)];

The scrollView is connected but it still won't scroll.  I have placed a label with text in the scroll view.  Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand you have added scrollview on storyboard still you are doing alloc?

Comment: I didn't mean to put that in...Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20318430/2274694

Comment: My ScrollView works if it's vertical, but won't do anything if horizontal? Any help?

Comment: Like I wrote in that answer I linked to, move `[self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(968, 263)];` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for that is you create a new `UIScrollView` which is not the one from storyboard and its frame is not set.

Comment: I have the scrollview from storyboard, then i connected to scrollerViewController.h (ctrl + drag).  I removed the alloc, didn't mean to have that in...Any ideas?

Comment: My ScrollView works if it's vertical, but won't do anything if horizontal? Any help?

Comment: Possibly content size is not big enough, try to set content size height larger than frame size's height.

Comment: Try to adjust 263 to a larger value and see what happens.